# GIT: cannot push to origin/master

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase, git-push

[image]

This is my situation.

I had pushed version 2.1.6, but it was buggy, so I reverted my filesystem to the 2.1.5 and I then made some changes which I tagged 2.1.7.

Now I cannot push 2.1.7 to origin/master as it says:
**Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.**

I am very lost now. What should I do, if I just want to discard 2.1.6, and set the origin/master to 2.1.7?

Comment: *e.g.hint: 'git pull ...'*.

Comment: Using `git pull` it goes in conflict. I would like to discard 2.1.6 completed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your current situation:

```
... ---A------------E master, 2.1.7
       \---B---C---D origin/master
```

Using `git pull --rebase` would help you reach this:

```
... ---A---B---C---D---E master, 2.1.7, origin/master
```

Finally, `git push` your changes:

```
git checkout master
git pull --rebase
git push
```

---

Or simply using `git push --force` would help you achieve this:

```
... ---A------------E master, 2.1.7
       \---B---C---D origin/master

git checkout master
git push --force

... ---A------------E master, 2.1.7, origin/master
```

Comment: `git push --force` that's exactly what I was looking for!!!! many thanks! In SourceTree, the git client I am using, it's not enabled by default, for safety reasons. But you can enable it from the preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated your code before pushing ?

use `git pull origin master` before you push anything.

I assume that you are using origin as a name for your remote. 
Origin is a remote. You can use `git remote --verbose` to see all the remote configured under your git folder.

You can use `git reset --hard` -> Resets the index and working tree. Any changes to tracked files in the working tree since  are discarded.

Comment: if I use `git pull` now, it goes into conflict.
Is there any way to reset to the origin/master to my current 2.1.7?

Comment: How many conflict files? meaning is it too many? or it looks what the changes/diff is valid?

Comment: git reset --hard -> Resets the index and working tree. Any changes to tracked files in the working tree since <commit> are discarded.

Comment: don't reset hard, you'll lose your changes. i think the OP doesn't understand what's happened to the remote, and doing a reset may lose work